# Using several open ids

Tags: support, login, authentication

I've got a Google id, but also a MyOpenID.

All my Stack Exchange accounts were created via the Google account id.

How can I setup Stack Exchange so that I can also login with MyOpenId; in order to be able to choose either Google or my openid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Head over to your [profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/858039/).

Once there, click on My Logins & click on Add more logins to add your MyOpenID account

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to your profile page, click on `my logins`.

[image: my logins]

At the bottom of the popup there is a link to `add more logins`.

[image: add more logins...]