# Log in with myopenid.com does not work any longer

Tags: support, openid, myopenid

I tried to log in with my myopenid.com account on SO, but I have only this answer:

```
Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
No OpenID endpoint found.
```

So, I had to create another account (this time on StackExchange), but I would like it to be merged with my previous account. The previous account also had no email address linked with it, or maybe I used the same email address than on my new account, so I cannot recover anything.

How could I ask for the merge of my two accounts? I have not a lot of reputation, but it is always better that restarting from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MyOpenID](http://myopenid.com/) appears to be down at the moment.  This will probably resolve itself once they fix their site.  For the future, you can [add multiple open ids](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118784/using-several-open-ids) in case you have trouble with a specific OpenID provider.  You should consider creating a Stack Exchange OpenID, as that will probably work as long as this site is working.

Comment: I have created a StackExchange OpenID. Would it be possible to merge my previous account with the current?

Comment: @Teetoo yes, just flag to the moderator on any account and with the link of the other account, requesting to merge the account