# How do I "flag a moderator" to get control of my now-orphaned account?

Tags: support, user-accounts, myopenid

I initially set up my account -- https://stackoverflow.com/users/3799/parvenu74 -- in the summer of 2008 when the site was still very much in beta. Since I used myopenid.com for authentication and myopenid.com is no longer with us, I would like to apply the credentials I created for this account to my former account so I can keep using that account.  In another question -- [Log in with myopenid.com does not work any longer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134193/) -- it was mentioned that all you need to do is 'flag a moderator' to get access to an account which can't authenticated anymore (because the authentication services is gone).

How do I flag a moderator to get access to my old account?

Comment: You need to contact the Stack Exchange team via the "contact us" link in the footer. Flagging for a moderator will do nothing, as there's nothing a moderator can do for you.